# If dim V = dim U and $S \circ T$ is onto, prove or disprove V and W are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb V \to \mathbb W$ and  $S: \mathbb W \to \mathbb U$ be linear maps. If dim $\mathbb V$= dim $\mathbb U$ and (S o T) is onto (composition), then $\mathbb V$ and $\mathbb W$ are isomorphic. Prove or disprove.

Since dim $\mathbb V$= dim $\mathbb U$, we know that $\mathbb V$ and $\mathbb U$ are isomorphic. Mot really sure how to continue.

Comment: Is $dim(W) < dim(V)$ possible? Is  $dim(W) > dim(V)$ possible?

Comment: I don't think either are possible as (S o T) is one to one.

Comment: This merely implies $Im(T) \cap ker(S) = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

To define a linear map is enough to define it on a basis and expand it linearly. For example the linear map $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ with $f(1,0)=(1,0,0), f(0,1)=(0,1,0)$ is the map
$$
f(x,y)=f(x(1,0)+y(0,1))=xf(1,0)+yf(0,1)=x(1,0,0)+y(0,1,0)=(x,y,0).
$$
Now define a linear map $g:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ by specifing what $g(1,0,0), g(0,1,0), g(0,0,1)$ are, such that $g\circ f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ is the identity and you will get your answer.